# Textview won't display data which has been updated in model (MVC)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, action

I've tried the following approaches to try to get the TextView to update from the model:

1. TextChangeListeners - error
2. Other Threads
3. asynctask
4. Added a refresh button which updates the data, I force the click

Scenario is as follows:

1. Standard thread running which updates the Model (MVC) object every second, which works perfectly.
2. When the Model object is updated, it notifies all classes which implement "Observer".
3. My GolfHomeScreen extends Activity and implements Observer (code below).
4. The GolfHomeScreen.update (Observable observable, Object data) method works perfectly. It executes every second as expected and S.O.P the correct data (see --> //*** #1 ***).
5. This then kicks off a Thread. I read on this site that you have to UI Thread to execute code which updates widgets and then run the "runOnUiThread" method - the code looked something like I have done below but I found it a little hard to follow. Anyway, this thread runs (see --> //*** #2** ) which then executes method onClick(View v) (see --> // **#3 ***).
6. `System.out.println("driverType :" + mvcModel.getDriverName());` (see --> //*** #4 ***) works perfectly.
7. //*** #5 *** - it MUST update but it doesn't.
8. If I actually physically click the button, the data is displayed correctly on the screen. My only guess is that the screen must not refresh on the forced click or else I am not using the UI thread to make the update.

NOTE: If the code below is missing something, it is because I removed a ton of code to simplify the understanding of what's going on.

```
public class GolfHomeScreen extends Activity implements Observer
{
    GolfHomeScreen golfHomeScreen = null;
    TextView driverName = null; // Type of driver used by golfer (eg: 1 wood)
    Button refreshData = null;

  @Override public void onClick(View v) //*** #3 ***
  {
    if ((v.getId()) == 12345) // ID of wood (12345 = 1 wood)
    {
                    //*** #4 ***
        System.out.println("driverType              :" + mvcModel.getDriverName()); //THIS PRINTS OUT THE LATEST DATA!!!

                    //*** #5 ***
                    driverName.setText(String.valueOf(mvcModel.getDriverName()));   //THIS DOESN'T AFFECT THE SCREEN?? WHY  :-(
    }
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    golfHomeScreen = this;
    refreshData = indViewById(R.id.golfhomescreen_button_refreshData);
    driverName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.golfhomescreen_text_drivername);
  }

  @Override public void update(Observable observable, Object data)
  {
     // #1 ***
    System.out.println("driverType              :" + mvcModel.getDriverName());

    golfHomeScreen.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            refreshData.performClick(); //*** #2 ***
        }
    });
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I'll run a few suggestions and a few fixes and hopefully your problem will be gone.
I'm saying that because conceptually you do have some wrong stuff, and my answer is kind of fixing those concepts:

- remove `GolfHomeScreen golfHomeScreen = null;` and `golfHomeScreen = this;` you don't need an object referencing to itself. It's just making confusion. This line `golfHomeScreen.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` you should just call `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`
- Change `System.out.pr***` to `Log.d(TAG, MESSAGE);` that's just because that is Android specialised way of dumping logs and it won't really matter for your result. It's nicer than standard Java System.out because allows you to filter those logs by TAG and severity.
- Do never call `refreshData.performClick();` or anything similar to that because you want the action inside that button to be performed. If you want a certain thing to happen from more than one source, create a method `doThatThing()`, put the actions in there, and from the `Click` and from the `Update`, you call the method. The way you're doing is a bit of a "Rube Goldberg machine" that is updating something, to click a button, to change a text. Just change the text.
- do never compare a view ID with a number `if ((v.getId()) == 12345)` the ID of views created from XML are generated by the system during compilation and you can't know if it's a fixed number. You should compare with the static int ID of that view, like this : `if(v.getId() == R.id.golfhomescreen_text_drivername)`. If the view was not created in XML (which is not the case here), you can compare with the actual object `if(v.equals(driverName))`

with those changes I believe your code will work. Make sure to let me know and mark as correct answer if in fact does.

Comment: Ignore the comment above - I need to fully test it properly, I'm running it on an old laptop at the mo and can't test it properly but it'd looking like it won't work!!! I'll report back more in a while when I'm back on my dec machine!!!

Comment: It doesn't work - I've changed my architecture as it's become too complicated!!!

I was stubborn for my own good!!! Thanks for responding though